# Windows version error when installing Android Studio 3.1 Preview 2

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error when trying to install Android Studio 3.1 Preview 2 on Windows:

> Error: CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>       with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>       system information and then contact the software publisher.

I have tried to install the following - but still didn't help:

```
Install jdk1.8.
```

I also tried the following in Android Studio:

`File->Project Structure->SDK Location (select your directory where the JDK is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK) -> Click OK`

But for some reason this produces error=216.

Comment: make sure you are using same combo of jdk, windows and android studio installation. If any one is different it will not work. if one is 32-bit every other must be 32-bit.

Comment: You may try with latest version of SDK.